# Firestore document stream and update

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the init, of my application I register a stream to one of the documents stored in firestore. Later I update a timestamp field in the same document. I should be getting one callback from the stream since there is only 1 update.

However, I am getting 2 callbacks -

1. Where that updated field is null
2. Where that updated field has the correct updated value

Any ideas why?

```
 CollectionReference collectionReference = FIRESTORE.collection("users");
 if(streamSub == null) {
  streamSub = collectionReference.document(documentID).snapshots().listen((onData){
    onData.data.forEach((k,v) => debugPrint(k + " = " + v.toString()));
  });
 }

//Update field
Firestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .document(documentID)
    .updateData({"Time" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp() })
```

Comment: There's not enough information here. Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect, both the update and the listener.

Comment: @DougStevenson updated with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting two callbacks because of your use of `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.  That value is actually a token that gets sent to Firestore servers, where the timestamp is determined and finally written to the database.  Locally on the client, the value isn't known at the time of the write, however, a write of the document still happens in the local cache.

Your listener is first getting the local cache write (before the timestamp is known), then again from the server after the timestamp is known.  You can look at the [snapshot metadata](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/metadata.html) to figure out the source of the data if that's important to you.

Comment: Thank you. Source isn't important for this case but good to know I can use metadata. So, technically I guess - it is still counted as 1 read and not two.

Comment: Yes, document data from local cache is not billed.  Billed reads only happen when data is transferred from the server.